# 8085 Assembly Language program to create an array in ascending order from 2 other arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, microprocessors, 8085

I have two arrays in ascending order that I need to combine to create a new array that is also in ascending order. One way I have though about doing this is putting one of the arrays into the new one, and then going through the second array and comparing every value in it to the ones in the new array and putting it in the right spot. This seems inefficient though.

I have also thought about comparing the first values of the array, and then comparing the one that doesn't get put in, to the next value of the other array.

What do you think of my ideas? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest way to do this is having one index for each of the arrays:

```
while(index_result < array_result_length)
    if (index1 < array1_length)
        if (index2 < array2_length)
            if (array1[index1] < array2[index2])
                array_result[index_result] = array1[index1]
                index1++
            else
                array_result[index_result] = array2[index2]
                index2++
        else
            array_result[index_result] = array1[index1]
            index1++
    else
         array_result[index_result] = array2[index2]
         index2++         
    index_result++
```